# Vertically resize grid item to fill row height

Tags: grid-layouts, user-interface, size

I am trying to find a way to have an item in a grid cell that always fill the available vertical space enforced by the remaining items (without enforcing any row height itself).

One of my (many) failed attempts:

```
Grid[{{
   Item[
    Style[
     Pane["", ImageSize -> {Scaled@1, Full}],
     Background -> Green
     ],
    ItemSize -> {1, Full}
    ],
   Style[
    Pane["", ImageSize -> {10, 200}],
    Background -> Yellow
    ]
   }},
 Frame -> All,
 Spacings -> 0
 ]
```

[image]

The green rectangle is supposed to fill the left cell entirely (and adjust its size if the size of the yellow rectangle is changed).

**Update:** The end goal of this is to have a cell-filling `EventHandler` expression. So anything of the form `Grid[{{EventHandler[…], …}}, …]` works for me, as long as the `EventHandler` fills the whole cell.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: if we are allowed to cheat: `Grid[{{Item[
    Button["", None, Appearance -> "FramedPalette", 
     Background -> Green], ItemSize -> {1, Full}], 
   Style[Pane["", ImageSize -> {10, 200}], Background -> Yellow]}}, 
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]`?

Comment: @kglr That's almost perfect, thanks! Any idea how to get rid of the frame that appears when hovering over the button? Sadly, changing the `Appearance` of the button to `None` seems to break the auto-sizing property of the button. (An explicit `ImageSize -> Full` doesn't seem to help either...)

Comment: I guess adding `Enabled->False` to the button and wrapping it in `EventHandler` does the trick, although it seems a bit hacky... Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Lukas, posted the comment as an answer. (Not sure about the `EventHandler` bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Grid[{{Item[Button["", None, Appearance -> "Palette", Enabled -> False, 
     Background -> Green], ItemSize -> {1, Full}], 
   Style[Pane["", ImageSize -> {10, 200}], Background -> Yellow]}}, 
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]